# Does lombok work with GWT super dev mode?

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea, lombok

I use lombok extensively at backend, it's really nice and I hope to integrate it into GWT, so I can take advantage of the magic.

I managed to let `gwt-maven-plugin` recognize lombok by using the  -`javaagent:lombok.jar=ECJ` vm args to be able to compile successfully, however, I'm not sure how to make it work with GWT super dev mode, as it continues complaining "missing getter method" in my IDE(Intellij IDEA).

Also tried the delombok goal of `lombok-maven-plugin` but without luck.
Any ideas?

Comment: Delombok works fine but might require some additional configuration (like adding the output dir as a source dir for the maven-compiler-plugin, and your IDE) There might be a Lombok plugin for IntelliJ too.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to delete your `workDir` before starting `gwt:run-codeserver`. This directory might contain files from previous (lombok-unaware) compilation attempts.

```
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.8.0-beta1:run-codeserver (default-cli) @ Web ---
[INFO] Turning off precompile in incremental mode.
[INFO] Super Dev Mode starting up
[INFO]    workDir: C:\Users\jzaruba\AppData\Local\Temp\gwt-codeserver-1653004051676437159.tmp
```

This is what my `mvn-gwt-codeserver.bat` looks like:

```
call mvn clean dependency:properties gwt:run-codeserver %*
```

(I added `dependency:properties` because my `gwt-maven-plugin` configuration refers to Lombok via project dependency: `${org.projectlombok:lombok:jar}`, i.e. no static path.)

And if you don't like launching the codeserver from command line, this is how "VM arguments" in my "GWT Codeserver" launch configuration look like:

```
-javaagent:path/to/lombok.jar=ECJ
```